# How to subset a survey object in R and use the tbl_svysummary with the add_difference function

Tags: r, survey, gtsummary

I have a survey that I need to filter to include only two specific categories for comparison. A simulation of it can be reproduced with this code:

```
library(survey)
library(gtsummary)
data(api)

svy <- survey::svydesign(id = ~dnum, weights = ~pw, data = apiclus1, fpc = ~fpc) 

svy <- subset(svy, stype %in% c("E", "H"))
```

And I am trying to use this code to create a table with the differences:

```
svy %>%
  tbl_svysummary(by = stype, include = c(api00, stype),
                 statistic = list(all_categorical() ~ "{p}%",
                     all_continuous() ~ "{mean}"),
    digits = ~ 2,
    missing = "no") %>% 
    add_difference()
```

And getting this error: Error: 'tbl_summary'/'tbl_svysummary' object must have a `by=` value with exactly two levels.

How could I drop the level to remain just 2 and therefore use add_difference?

I use the filter in the dataframe, but I'm afraid it will cause me to lose the lifting weights.

Editing this post from the answer from @astra bellow, I've made a small example with my data, but it not works. Works only with the example above

```
install.packages("PNSIBGE")
library(PNSIBGE)
library(tidyverse)
pns <- get_pns(year = 2019, labels = T)
pns.2 <- subset(pns, C009  %in% c("Branca", "Preta")) 
pns.2$variables$C009 <- droplevels(pns.2$variables$C009)
pns.2 %>%
    tbl_svysummary(by = C009, include = c(C006)) %>% 
    add_difference()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `droplevels()` function:

```r
svy$variables$stype %<>% droplevels
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @astra! It worked perfectly on the example. But, not in my data. I do not know why. I've tried to do a small example with my data. Do you have a gess why it not work? Thank you anyway

```
library(PNSIBGE)
library(tidyverse)

pns <- get_pns(year = 2019, labels = T)

pns.2 <- subset(pns, C009  %in% c("Branca", "Preta")) 

pns.2$variables$C009 <- droplevels(pns.2$variables$C009)

pns.2 %>%
    tbl_svysummary(by = C009, include = c(C006)) %>% 
    add_difference()
```

Comment: I cannot download the data.

Is `pns` a data frame or a survey object?

Comment: @astra seems to have solved the issue. Unless you can update the post with something reproducible that we can run on our machines, not sure what else can be done for you.

Comment: Sorry, @astra. pns is a survey object. It is obtained by the get_pns() function of the PNSIBGE package. It is produceable with these codes: `
``` 
install.packages("PNSIBGE")
library(PNSIBGE)
pns <- get_pns(year = 2019, labels = T)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is your problem:

```
> str(pns.2$variables$C009)
 Factor w/ 6 levels "Branca","Preta",..: 1 4 2 2 4 2 1 1 4 4 ...
> table(pns.2$variables$C009)

  Branca    Preta  Amarela    Parda Indígena Ignorado 
   99019    28304     1698   148273     2064       24 
> svytable(~C009,pns.2)
C009
  Branca    Preta  Amarela    Parda Indígena Ignorado 
91037722 21786515        0        0        0        0
```

The issue is that a survey design object isn't just a data frame. In particular, your one has post-stratification information in it. In that situation (and some others) the `survey` package removes observations by setting the weight to zero rather than by dropping rows (dropping rows is a computational shortcut that isn't always available).

So, you can't just use `droplevels`, because all the levels are (correctly) still there. If you're working with functions from the `survey` package you can use `factor` with an explicit set of levels

```
> svytotal(~factor(C009,levels=c("Branca","Preta")), pns.2,na.rm=TRUE)
                                                     total     SE
factor(C009, levels = c("Branca", "Preta"))Branca 91037722 686604
factor(C009, levels = c("Branca", "Preta"))Preta  21786515 338021
```

or equivalently

```
> pns.2<-update(pns.2, C009new=factor(C009,levels=c("Branca","Preta")))
> svytotal(~C009new, pns.2,na.rm=TRUE)
                 total     SE
C009newBranca 91037722 686604
C009newPreta  21786515 338021
```

but that doesn't seem to work with `tbl_svysummary`.

Comment: Ahh, very interesting. With that in mind, I think if you create a copy of your by variable that is a character rather than a factor, you can create the table with `tbl_svysummary()`. (But I am not at my computer to test)

Comment: No, I tried that. `tbl_svysummary` converts it to the factor with all the levels

Comment: Very interesting! I've learned a lot with your post, @Thomas Lumley!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the default test used by `add_difference()` is a "t.test" and such test is not available for a table produced by `tbl_svysummary()`. You should use "smd" method. See https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tests.html#tbl-svysummary-add-difference-

Second, to manipulate survey objects, it is often easier to use srvyr package which allows to use dplyr verbs.

```r
library(survey)
#> Le chargement a nécessité le package : grid
#> Le chargement a nécessité le package : Matrix
#> Le chargement a nécessité le package : survival
#> 
#> Attachement du package : 'survey'
#> L'objet suivant est masqué depuis 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     dotchart
library(srvyr)
#> 
#> Attachement du package : 'srvyr'
#> L'objet suivant est masqué depuis 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
library(gtsummary)
library(forcats)

data(api)

svy <- apiclus1 |> 
  as_survey_design(id = dnum, weights = pw, fpc = fpc) |> 
  filter(stype %in% c("E", "H")) |> 
  mutate(stype = fct_drop(stype))

svy  |> 
  tbl_svysummary(
    by = stype,
    include = api00,
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"
  ) |> 
  add_difference(test = all_continuous() ~ "smd") |> 
  as_kable()
```

| **Characteristic** | **E**, N = 4,874 | **H**, N = 474 | **Difference** | **95% CI** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| api00 | 649 (106) | 619 (97) | 0.30 | 0.21, 0.40 |

<sup>Created on 2024-02-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much, Joseph, for the explanation and example. The code worked with the data api, but not with my survey. I just encountered the same problem as before. It worked with a generic example (data(api)), but not in my case. Thomas Lumley gave an excellent explanation above why. With my survey I used the code below and still getting this error: ````Erro: 'tbl_summary'/'tbl_svysummary' object must have a `by=` value with exactly two levels```

Comment: The code for reprodction of what I citede above: 
install.packages("PNSIBGE")
library(PNSIBGE)
library(tidyverse)
library(survey)
library(srvyr)
library(gtsummary)
library(forcats)

pns <- get_pns(year = 2019, labels = T)

class(pns)

pns.2 <- pns %>% 
  srvyr::as_survey() %>% 
  filter(C009 %in% c("Branca", "Preta")) %>%  
  mutate(C009 = fct_drop(C009))

pns.2 %>% 
  tbl_svysummary(
    by = C009,
    include = C006,
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"
  ) |> 
  add_difference(test = all_continuous() ~ "smd") |> 
  as_kable()

Comment: It seems that there is a problem with this subset, resulting with a strata having only one PSU.

```
> pns.2 <- pns %>% 
+   srvyr::as_survey() %>% 
+   filter(C009 %in% c("Branca", "Preta")) %>% 
+   mutate(C009 = fct_drop(C009))
Message d'avis :
Dans subset_svy_vars.survey.design2(.data, !!!dots, .preserve = .preserve) :
  1 strata have only one PSU in this subset.
```

Comment: This error is resulting later with a problem when computing SMD. I am not sure that the problem is coming from gtsummary, but rather with an issue with this specific subset.

Comment: The first thing is to check if you can do manually perform the computation with survey only. I'm not familiar with this data, but I have a feeling that this subset is not valid.